# Can't compile java-file on Ubuntu with special character å, ä, ö (works on windows)

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, encoding, compilation

I've got a java-file containing the swedish characters å,ä,ö (I have to include these in the file, I'm parsing an ISO-8859-1, latin1 text-file which includes these). The file compiles and runs on a windows computer.

While compiling the file on Ubuntu in bash I am getting following error however:

```
ConstructDatabase.java:76: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
        case '?': return 27;
              ^
ConstructDatabase.java:77: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
        case '?': return 28;
              ^
ConstructDatabase.java:78: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
        case '?': return 29;
```

I tried using the `javac -encoding ISO-8859-1` flag, which makes the file compile, but not work as intended. I also tried using the `export LC_ALL=C` command (I'm not sure why it would affect the java compiling, but it was suggested in other threads) but it still doesn't work.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The compiler has to know the character encoding used to write the file. In order to tell it, you have to know the character encoding used to write the file and how to tell it. For the latter, try `javac -help` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The compile error gives most of the information necessary: "unmappable character for encoding ASCII". That means, the compiler expects the Java source files to be encoded in ASCII, and ASCII doesn't contain these characters.

Your source files somehow contain the swedish characters, maybe encoded as ISO-8859-1, maybe as UTF-8 (just to mention the most likely ones). You have to find out which one your source files are using (that's not a trvial task).

Your Ubuntu environment seems to be using ASCII as default encoding. Then echoing the source file to the terminal might give you a hint. If instead of the swedish character you see a combination of two cryptic characters, then the file might be UTF-8 encoded.

You have to tell the correct encoding to the compiler on Ubuntu. And as `javac -encoding ISO-8859-1` doesn't work as expected, I'd guess that your files are encoded in UTF-8, so `javac -encoding UTF-8` might be the solution.

And instead of messing around with the encodings, you can replace the characters in the source file with the \uxxxx escapes. That will work in ASCII, UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 and all other encodings based on ASCII.